# Are both of these algorithms valid implementations of LZSS?

Tags: algorithm, compression

I am reverse engineering things and I often stumble upon various decompression algorithms. Most of times, it's LZSS just like Wikipedia describes it:

> 1. Initialize dictionary of size 2^n
> 2. While output is less than known output size:
>
>    1. Read *flag*
>    2. If the *flag* is set, output literal byte (and append it at the end of dictionary)
>    3. If the *flag* is not set:
>
>       1. Read *length* and *look behind position*
>       2. Transcribe *length* bytes from the dictionary at *look behind position* to the output and at the end of dictionary.

The thing is that the implementations follow two schools of how to encode the *flag*. The first one treats the input as sequence of bits:

> 2. (...)
>
>    1. Read *flag* as one bit
>    2. If it's set, read literal byte as 8 unaligned bits
>    3. If it's not set, read length and position as *n* and *m* unaligned bits

This involves lots of bit shift operations.

The other one saves a little CPU time by using bitwise operations only for *flag* storage, whereas literal bytes, length and position are derived from aligned input bytes. To achieve this, it breaks the linearity by fetching a few *flags* in advance. So the algorithm is modified like this:

> 2. (...)
>
>    1. Read 8 *flags* at once by reading one byte. For each of these 8 flags:
>
>       1. If it's set, read literal as aligned byte
>       2. If it's not set, read length and position as aligned bytes (deriving the specific values from the fetched bytes involves some bit operations, but it's nowhere as expensive as the first version.)

My question is: are these both valid LZSS implementations, or did I identify these algorithms wrong? Are there any known names for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are effectively variants on LZSS, since all use one bit to decide on literal vs. match.  More generally they are variants on LZ77.

Deflate is also a variant on LZ77, which does not use a whole bit for literal vs. match.  Instead deflate has a single code for the combination of literals and lengths, so the code implicitly determines whether the next thing is a literal or a match.  A length code is followed by a separate distance code.

[lz4](http://fastcompression.blogspot.com/2011/05/lz4-explained.html) (a specific algorithm, not a family) handles byte alignment in a different way, coding the *number* of literals, which is necessarily followed by a match.  The first byte with the number of literals also has part of the distance.  The literals are byte aligned, as is the offset that follows the literals and the rest of the distance.